# Mounting SD card as USB drive on Windows PC (Marshmallow)

Tags: usb-connection-mode

Since its beginnings, crappy Android has made it difficult for users to achieve the very basic feature of mounting the SD storage of the phone as a USB drive, when the phone is connected to a PC by cable. You can see the phone and SD under My Computer, but not as a USB drive that apps can access. My workaround to this embarrassing shortcoming has been an app that did just that but that only works on a rooted phone - which my new Marshmallow Android phone is not. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Do you have a SD card slot in your computer?

Comment: Not a micro SD slot . Plus I would like to be able to access the card as a drive letter while connecting the phone to the PC via cable

Comment: Goggling threw [this option](http://www.mtpdrive.com/index.html) mentioned [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/495665-how-mount-mtp-ptp-drive-letter-usb-mass-storage-ums.html)

Comment: Similar Question: **[Drive letter for MTP connection under Windows](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/drive-letter-for-mtp-connection-under-windows)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, it's possible only if your device is rooted..
**Google no longer supports** USB Mass Storage Mode [due to several reasons](http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/), since JellyBean.

However, there are softwares for PC that virtually shows & provides access to the device (connected in MTP mode) as a Removable Storage USB Drive, like for example, **[MTPdrive](http://www.mtpdrive.com/)** (as @beeshyams commented); no root access required in device. But it's just a virtual round-about connection, hence it'll be slower than UMS & even MTP mode..

Or try **[WiFi USB Disk - Smart Disk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.smartdisk.mounter&hl=en)**, which also virtually shows your device as a USB Drive (through WiFi). Or you can do that yourself [using file servers by mapping a network drive to your device](http://d0bon.blogspot.in/2014/07/map-drive-letter-to-android-mtp.html).

To get your device's memory card actually mounted as a real UMS device, the only way is to root your device..

There are many root apps that would help you enable UMS. Some of them are:

1. **Multi Mount SD-Card** ( [Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rafoid.multimountsdcard.widget.free&hl=en) | [Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rafoid.multimountsdcard.widget&hl=en) )
2. **USB Mass Storage Enabler** ([an app created by me](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-universal-mass-storage-enabler-beta-t3240097))
3. **USB Sharer** ( [Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.devwom.usbsharereval) | [Full](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=os.devwom.usbsharer&hl=en) )
4. **SD Card as USB Drive** ( [Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rotturm.mtpusbswitcher) )

Note: Some apps require you to disable SELinux (that is, setting SELinux mode to 'Permissive' by `setenforce 0` command)

Comment: Might also help: **[Using SMB server without root access](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/using-smb-server-without-root-access/31807#31807)**